# Send Message to remote PC in local network

Tags: c#, wmi, message-queue

How can I in c# send Message box to remote computer? I have credentials of remote PC and know PC name. Can use for this purpose WMI?

Comment: You want to make a message box appear on the display of a remote computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `NET SEND` command. However, the messenger service needs to be enabled on the remote computer - you could use PSEXEC to start this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking how to send a message to a remote computer via c#.  If so, you have several options see below:

[Microsoft message queuing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(VS.85).aspx) - Only if you need a super robust framework that gauarantees delivery of your message even if destination goes offline.

[UDP multicast message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) - You can use the System.NET.Sockets namespace to send UDP packets and build a client to listen for them which can be run of n number of remote server.  This is not error checking and if the remote server is not up then you are out of luck.

[TCP socket connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) - You can use the System.NET.Sockets namespace to send TCP packets and build a client to listen for them which can be run of n number of remote server.  This is error checking and if the remote server is not up then you are out of luck.

Hope this gives you some direction.

Enjoy!

Comment: I try to use message queuing but exception through that shows that queuing is not install on machine. I want some universal Technic which not depend on what is installed on remote PC.